# Access to the origen save command programmatically

Tags: origen-sdk

I created a build command that runs the `origen program` command in a loop and I would to run the `origen save` command on a per file basis.  The reason for this is because I remove some of the created files (e.g. .pmfl) because they don't fit our usage model.  If I try to run the `origen save new` command, the following error occurs because of the deleted files.

```
peologin07:ppekit $ origen save all
cp: cannot stat `../scan/origen/ft1/vectors/Flow_global.pmfl': No such file or directory
Reference updated!
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at updating the save command to not crash when it encounters something like that.

There is not really a programmable API for it since the save command is little more than grepping the last log file and executing the copy commands that it finds in there.

These copy operations are not currently stored anywhere for later programmatic access, they are just written to the log and forgotten about.